# Is implicit global using static supposed to work in C# 10 / .net 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I have a Common project with the following 2 usings

```
global using global::System.IO;
global using static global::System.Console;
```

both are visible within the Common project itself.

When I reference the Common project in another project

```
global using global::System.IO;
```

works in the main project as well however

```
global using static global::System.Console;
```

does not.

Why not?

PS I do have the following in both projects.

```
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

**EDIT:** By "does not" I mean the WriteLine method is not visible. In Common I can just go "WriteLine" but in the referencing project I need to go "Console.WriteLine".

**EDIT:** The reason I thought it should be supported is because of the following comment in: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145

[image]

Said user seems to suggest that the proposed feature is not necessary because of the implicit global using statics being possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "... does not"? Do you get an error? Unexpected or no results? What really happens?

Comment: System.Console is a type name, not a namespace name.  Using `using` on a type name is not affected in any way by ImplicitUsings, like it was for System.IO.  Do scratch the idea that `global using` infects from referenced projects, that would be horrible.

Comment: See edit. Do you have some documentation that substantiates your comment?

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub comment in your screenshot only shows a global `using static` in a single project. There are no project references involved.

Global usings only work in a single project. The reason why the global using for `System.IO` works in your main project is that this namespace is included by `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>`. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives)